# Eliminar cadenas de texto que empiecen y acaben en "<" y ">"

Tags: php, string

Andaba buscando cómo hacer que en un `string` elimine todos los substring que empiecen y acaben por **"<"** y **">"**. ¿Alguien me puede guiar?

Edito: Sí, me refería a las etiquetas con todo su contenido.

Comment: Hola @E.R.A bienvenido a SO en español, coloca el código que has intentando hasta ahora, para poder guiarte de mejor manera. También especifica un poco mejor que es lo que quieres lograr, quieres eliminar solo los símbolos < > o quieres eliminar todo el contenido que esté entre estos simbolos?

Comment: @E.R.A. Creo que sería bueno **[edit]** la pregunta aclarando si te estás refiriendo a etiquetas HTML o a otra cosa.

Answer (score 3):

Con la función [str_replace()](http://php.net/manual/es/function.str-replace.php)
puedes reemplazar todos los símbolos `<` y `>` por un espacio.

[Ver Demo 1](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/a0f921f549f912ad214c8aefa208effc04f7c562)

```
$string = '<a> <span> <p>';

echo str_replace(['<', '>'], ' ', $string);

// output:  a   span   p
```

Para eliminar todos los *strings* que empiezan con el símbolo `<` y termina `>` se puede utilizar la función [preg_replace()](http://php.net/manual/es/function.preg-replace.php) y con el regex `(?:<|&lt;)\/?([a-zA-Z]+) *[^<\/]*?(?:>|&gt;)`

[Ver demo 2](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/9594b91b65f37aedd37ec0863a32e759d9c5dcff)

```
$string = '<abcd>hola<efgh><ijkl>bonito<mnop><qrs>mundo!<tuvw>';

echo preg_replace('/(?:<|&lt;)\/?([a-zA-Z]+) *[^<\/]*?(?:>|&gt;)/', ' ', $string);

// output: hola bonito mundo!
```

Comment: o yo he entendido mal o me parece que el OP quiere eliminar todo lo que esta entre `<` y `>` y no solo los símbolos

Comment: @blonfu - voy a dejar las 2 opciones... quizás le sirva

Comment: La demo 2 fallaría con `'<abcd data-ejemplo="a > b">hola'`

Comment: @Mariano - Tienes razón... pero dice que empieza con `<` y acaba con `>`... estás libre de contestar con una respuesta que elimine todas las posibilidades

Comment: @aldanux La mayoría de estas preguntas siempre apuntan a eliminar tags HTML. Recomendaría usar `strip_tags()`, para lo cual ya hay una respuesta.

Answer (score 2):

Se podría usar la función [strip-tags](http://php.net/manual/es/function.strip-tags.php) o una expresión regular para que por medio de la función[preg-replace](http://php.net/manual/es/function.preg-replace.php) reemplazar dichos tags

```
$variable = "<adsd>Muy<efgh><xxx><qrs>Bien!<mmm>";
echo strip_tags($variable,'<\S>');
echo preg_replace('#<[^>]+>#', ' ', $variable);
```

Comment: Sin duda `strip_tags()` es la función para este caso, por lo que no recomendaría hacerlo con expresiones regulares... aún cuando tu regex sea el más eficiente de lo que se respondió, hay casos que lo harían fallar.

Comment: Creo lo mismo. hay que ser bien minucioso con las expresiones regulares porque pueden presentar fallos para determinados casos.

Comment: Ya tenés mi +1 por ser quien recomendó la respuesta con `strip_tags()`... Yo dejaría sólo esa respuesta (eliminando el regex).